# Python: pandas categorical series with datetime indexing breaks on attempt to change values (ValueError)

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data, python-datetime

(I'm using pandas version 0.23.4 on Python 3.6.6)

I have a Pandas series with a datetime index that holds categorical data.

```
my_range = pd.date_range("2018-01-01", "2018-01-05", freq="D")
my_series = pd.Series(data=pd.Categorical(values=["a", "b", "c", "a", "b"], categories=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]),
                      index=my_range)
print(my_series)
```

It looks like this:

```
2018-01-01    a
2018-01-02    b
2018-01-03    c
2018-01-04    a
2018-01-05    b
Freq: D, dtype: category
Categories (5, object): [a, b, c, d, e]
```

I can access values by indexing with strings that get matched to the datetimes:

```
print(my_series["2018-01-03"])
```

Outputs:

```
c
```

I can change values by ordinary indexing:

```
my_series[0] = "d"
print(my_series)
```

Outputs:

```
2018-01-01    d
2018-01-02    b
2018-01-03    c
2018-01-04    a
2018-01-05    b
Freq: D, dtype: category
Categories (5, object): [a, b, c, d, e]
```

But when I try to alter values by indexing with the datetime string, it doesn't work and gives a ValueError:

```
my_series["2018-01-03"] = "b"
```

Outputs:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-48f5e1a05df9> in <module>
      1 print(my_series["2018-01-03"])
----> 2 my_series["2018-01-03"] = "b"

D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
    937         # do the setitem
    938         cacher_needs_updating = self._check_is_chained_assignment_possible()
--> 939         setitem(key, value)
    940         if cacher_needs_updating:
    941             self._maybe_update_cacher()

D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in setitem(key, value)
    933                     pass
    934 
--> 935             self._set_with(key, value)
    936 
    937         # do the setitem

D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _set_with(self, key, value)
    981                 self._set_values(key.astype(np.bool_), value)
    982             else:
--> 983                 self._set_labels(key, value)
    984 
    985     def _set_labels(self, key, value):

D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _set_labels(self, key, value)
    991         mask = indexer == -1
    992         if mask.any():
--> 993             raise ValueError('%s not contained in the index' % str(key[mask]))
    994         self._set_values(indexer, value)
    995 

ValueError: ['2' '0' '1' '8' '-' '0' '1' '-' '0' '3'] not contained in the index
```

However, no such problem occurs when the datatype is numeric instead of categorical:

```
new_series = pd.Series(data=[10, 11, 12, 13, 14], index=my_range)
new_series["2018-01-03"] = 20
print(new_series)
```

Outputs:

```
2018-01-01    10
2018-01-02    11
2018-01-03    20
2018-01-04    13
2018-01-05    14
Freq: D, dtype: int64
```

Why does it break when the datatype is categorical?

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12862

Comment: Using .loc to assign